# passing csv contents to template

Tags: django

Passing csv contents to template. And getting error. thanks

```
  def ....
    with open('csv', 'rb') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
    return render(request, template, {"results": reader})
```

Error

```
I/O operation on closed file
```

[Full Traceback](http://dpaste.org/ffXLn/)

Comment: Please fix the indentation, because as written your code is not valid Python, and secondly, paste the full traceback.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Indentation correct in my code. But I've fixed in stack. full traceback added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with` introduces a new context manager, which in the case of a file takes care of closing its argument after it ends. However, your context manager ends in the very next line, so by the time the `render` function is called, the file is closed, and the csv reader can't operate.

You could probably just move the `return` one indentation to the right, or better call render within the `with` but save it to a variable which you subsequently pass to `return`:

```
with open('csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    html = render(request, template, {"results": reader})
return html
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing a reader object to the template (where you iterate over it), however since it is out of the `with` block, the file is closed.

To remedy the situation, one approach would be to convert the generator into some iterable sequence.

For example:

```
def foo(request):
    lines = []
    with open('foo.csv', 'rb') as f:
        lines = [line for line in csv.reader(f)]
    return render(request, template, {'results': lines})
```